# How to use rasa nlu from python?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa

I am able to use rasa from terminal using following commands.

```
rasa nlu train
rasa nlu shell
```

Now i want to do same my python code. How do i do it?

I have my nlu.md and config.yml. I saw this link https://legacy-docs.rasa.com/docs/nlu/0.15.1/python/ but it talks demo-rasa.json which i dont have.

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, those docs are for old versions of rasa - I'd recommend using the latest version (or at least `>1.0`) and checking out the new docs here https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/

Your question has some answers on the forum e.g.: 
https://forum.rasa.com/t/training-models-from-a-python-script-python-api-in-the-new-rasa-1-0/12482

https://forum.rasa.com/t/python-api-for-nlu-interpreter-and-agent/22710

For training a model, it'll look something like:

```
    from rasa.train import train_nlu


    model_directory = <model output dir>
    config_file = <path to config file>
    nlu_data = <path to NLU training folder or file>

    train_nlu(
            config=config_file,
            nlu_data=nlu_data,
            output=model_directory
        )
```

Comment: do they support rasa 2?

Comment: No, Rasa requires Python 3.7 or 3.8